# Como centrar estos elementos

Tags: css, css3

Buenas, estoy intentanto centrar los títulos **"Mis destrezas"**, **"Que podemos abarcar"** y **también el conjunto de imágenes de abajo**.

El problema es que si le pongo un `text-align:center` a su contenedor, el párrafo también se me centra y eso no me interesa.

¿Como se soluciona esto?¿Como centro solo esos 3 elementos?

```css
.General-Destrezas {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.Destrezas {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: auto;
}

.Texto-Destrezas {
  text-indent: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Resaltar-Destreza {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Listado-Destrezas {
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Tecnologias-Destrezas {
  list-style: none;
  /* Lista horizontal */
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Tecnologias-Destrezas img {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="General General-Destrezas">

  <a name="Conoceme"></a>

  <div class="Destrezas">
    <h2>Mis destrezas</h2>

    <p class="Texto-Destrezas">
      Tengo la titulación de <span class="Resaltar-Destreza">Técnico Superior en Regulación y Control de Sistemas Automáticos</span> y actualmente estoy cursando el <span class="Resaltar-Destreza">Grado de Ingeniería Electrónica Industrial y Automática</span>.
    </p>

    <h3>¿Que podemos abarcar? </h3>

    <ul class="Listado-Destrezas">
      <li> Podemos desarrollar proyectos web desde sus inicios, planteando una idea, desarrollando su código y diseñando un aspecto acorde a sus necesidades.</li>
      <br>
      <li> Desarrollo de software para cualquier funcionalidad deseada, en todas sus etapas del proceso. </li>
      <br>
      <li> ¿Te atreves a robotizar tu casa? Desarrollo de placas de arduino, PLCs, para tener los mayores avances y comodidades en tu hogar, oficina o negocio. </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="Tecnologias-Destrezas">
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-HTML.png" alt="HTML"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-CSS.png" alt="CSS"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-JS.png" alt="JS"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-SQL.png" alt="SQL"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-PHP.png" alt="PHP"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-C.png" alt="C"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-PSD.png" alt="PSD"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.General-Destrezas {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.Destrezas {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: auto;
}

.Texto-Destrezas {
  text-indent: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Resaltar-Destreza {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Listado-Destrezas {
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Tecnologias-Destrezas {
  list-style: none;
  /* Lista horizontal */
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Tecnologias-Destrezas img {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="General General-Destrezas">

  <a name="Conoceme"></a>

  <div class="Destrezas">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Mis destrezas</h2>

    <p class="Texto-Destrezas">
      Tengo la titulación de <span class="Resaltar-Destreza">Técnico Superior en Regulación y Control de Sistemas Automáticos</span> y actualmente estoy cursando el <span class="Resaltar-Destreza">Grado de Ingeniería Electrónica Industrial y Automática</span>.
    </p>

    <h3>¿Que podemos abarcar? </h3>

    <ul class="Listado-Destrezas">
      <li> Podemos desarrollar proyectos web desde sus inicios, planteando una idea, desarrollando su código y diseñando un aspecto acorde a sus necesidades.</li>
      <br>
      <li> Desarrollo de software para cualquier funcionalidad deseada, en todas sus etapas del proceso. </li>
      <br>
      <li> ¿Te atreves a robotizar tu casa? Desarrollo de placas de arduino, PLCs, para tener los mayores avances y comodidades en tu hogar, oficina o negocio. </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="Tecnologias-Destrezas">
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-HTML.png" alt="HTML"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-CSS.png" alt="CSS"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-JS.png" alt="JS"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-SQL.png" alt="SQL"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-PHP.png" alt="PHP"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-C.png" alt="C"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-PSD.png" alt="PSD"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Debes colocar en las etiquetas un text-align:center

Answer (score 0):

Los elementos h1, h2, h3, h4 y h5 son elementos de bloque, lo que significa que ocuparan todo el ancho de la linea. Si le especificas text-align:center solo ellos, se aliniaran en el centro. Le agregre una clase llamada `t-center` a los titulos que los centra a ambos.

Y en cuanto las imagenes es dificil ya que no publicaste siquiera una para saber las dimenciones de las mismas y centrarlas perfectamente.

```css
.General-Destrezas {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.Destrezas {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: auto;
}

.Texto-Destrezas {
  text-indent: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Resaltar-Destreza {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Listado-Destrezas {
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Tecnologias-Destrezas {
  list-style: none;
  /* Lista horizontal */
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Tecnologias-Destrezas img {
  height: 90px;
}

.t-center{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="General General-Destrezas">

  <a name="Conoceme"></a>

  <div class="Destrezas">
    <h2 class="t-center">Mis destrezas</h2>

    <p class="Texto-Destrezas">
      Tengo la titulación de <span class="Resaltar-Destreza">Técnico Superior en Regulación y Control de Sistemas Automáticos</span> y actualmente estoy cursando el <span class="Resaltar-Destreza">Grado de Ingeniería Electrónica Industrial y Automática</span>.
    </p>

    <h3 class="t-center">¿Que podemos abarcar? </h3>

    <ul class="Listado-Destrezas">
      <li> Podemos desarrollar proyectos web desde sus inicios, planteando una idea, desarrollando su código y diseñando un aspecto acorde a sus necesidades.</li>
      <br>
      <li> Desarrollo de software para cualquier funcionalidad deseada, en todas sus etapas del proceso. </li>
      <br>
      <li> ¿Te atreves a robotizar tu casa? Desarrollo de placas de arduino, PLCs, para tener los mayores avances y comodidades en tu hogar, oficina o negocio. </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="Tecnologias-Destrezas">
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-HTML.png" alt="HTML"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-CSS.png" alt="CSS"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-JS.png" alt="JS"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-SQL.png" alt="SQL"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-PHP.png" alt="PHP"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-C.png" alt="C"></li>
      <li><img src="Img/Icono-PSD.png" alt="PSD"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El texto no esta centrado, es que tienes la propiedad `text-indent: 20px;` aplicada al contenido y eso hace parecer que esta centrado tambien.

Comment: Gracias! En cuanto a las imágenes, es que no se como se suben aquí... Si te fijas las he metido en un listado y les he dado un alto de 90px, yo pensé que el centrado sería un proceso equivalente para los títulos que para ellas

Comment: Ya, perdón me di cuenta justp después. Mil gracias

Comment: Recuerda marcarla si era la respuesta que buscabas.